# Getting 400 Request TimeOut error on trying to do a POST request from node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Below is the explanation in detail

**I have setup the post data**

```js
var post_data = JSON.stringify({
    "primaryContact": {
        "id": 'contact_id'
    },
    "subject": "subject"
});
```

**Setup the https module options**

```js
var https_options_post = {
    host: hostName,
    method: 'POST',
    path: "/services/rest/connect/v1.3/incidents",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data),
        'Authorization': auth
    }
}
```

**Created a function which handles POST request**

```js
function postJSON(https_options_post, callback) {
    var request = https.request(https_options_post, function (response) {
        console.log('In POST Request Function block');
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(body);
            var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
            var result = "Incident Reference Number: " + bodyJSON.lookupName;
            callback(null, result);
        });
        response.on('error', callback);
    })
    .on('error', callback)
    .end();
```

**Called the function**

```js
postJSON(https_options_post, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error while retrieving Data: ', err);
  }
    console.log(result);
});
```

**But the returned response is**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>408 Request Time-out</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Request Time-out</h1>
    <p>Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I hit the API in the chrome using REST client extension and pass on the basic auth parameters the return from server is JSON. Please help and tell if something wrong in the code.

Comment: Try without `content-Length` header

Comment: Hi Malice, If I do it without content-length header then how post_data will be sent to server? In node.js doc http.request() function's 1st argument can be a JSON object with various inputs as described above. Its doesn't have anything like body key which can be equated to post_data by which the json input can be sent.

Comment: Oh sorry, But are you writing your `post_data` into the stream created inside `postJSON` ? You are directly ending it

Comment: You will need `request.write(post_data)` somewhere in there. The server is waiting for the data of the length you supplied, but you never sent it :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton Malice, I can't believe I missed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data being written into the `request` stream and the server keeps expects `Content-Length` bytes of data. Writing `request.write(post_data)` before `request.end()` solved it

Answer (score 0):

**Confluence with Node.js Example Reference:**

```
reqGet.write(jsonObject)
reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Code copied Ref & full example on,
https://www.snippetbucket.com/confluence-nodejs-rest-api/